# question about summation?

Tags: summation

Are there any general rules to find

$???\leqslant \sum_{n=t}^{m}f(n)\leqslant ???$

when $m$ and $t$ $\in $ R

Comment: are the properties of the function (monotony,continuity,..) given?

Comment: no only on general 
if thier is no answer so
f(n) is continuity when n $in$ R

Comment: Well then: no, there is no such general rule for such a general function $\,f\,$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial, yet sometimes useful, inequality is $$(m-t+1)\min_{i\in\{t,t+1,...,m\}}f(i)\leq\sum_{n=t}^{m}\ f(n) \leq(m-t+1)\max_{i\in\{t,t+1,...,m\}}f(i)$$

Answer (score 1):

There is always :

$$\sum_{n=t}^m f(n)\le (m-t+1)\max_{x\in E}\left| f(x)\right|\; \text{ where }\; E = \{t,t+1,…,m-1,m\}$$

Comment: I think its $m-t+1$. If you sum from $1$ to $2$ you have $(2-1)+1$ elements in the sum

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the expression
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,n\, = \,a}^{\;b} {f(n)} 
$$
has a very precise and rigourous definition, valid for $a$ and $b$ real or even complex,
as far as $f(n)$ is defined also for $n$ real or complex.

The definition is given by the [Indefinite Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum), that is
$$
f(x) = \Delta _x F(x) = F(x + 1) - F(x)\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \sum\nolimits_{\,n\, = \,a}^{\;b} {f(n)}  = F(b) - F(a)
$$

Example:
$$
f(n) = n\quad  \to \quad f(x) = x\quad  \to \quad \Delta _x \left( {{{x\left( {x - 1} \right)} \over 2}} \right)
$$
so that
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,n\, = \,a}^{\;b} n  = {{b\left( {b - 1} \right) - a\left( {a - 1} \right)} \over 2} = {{\left( {b - a} \right)\left( {b + a - 1} \right)} \over 2}
$$

Finally note that for integral bounds we have
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,n\, = \,p}^{\;q} n  = \sum\limits_{p\, \le \,\,n\, < \,q} n  = \sum\limits_{p\, \le \,\,n\, \le \,q - 1} n \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;p \le q \hfill \cr 
  \;p,q \in Z \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$